# What work of science-fiction first introduced the concept of "Glassing" or Alpha-Striking a planet?

Tags: spaceship, weapon, origins

From the [Halo Wiki](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Glassing%E2%80%8ECached):

> The term glassing, also known as plasma bombardment, is used to refer to the act by which Covenant ships **bombard a planet from orbit** using heavy plasma weaponry.

This concept of bombarding a planet and turning it to glass is not unique to the Halo series alone.  The science-fiction video game [Iji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iji) also has an alien species that renders a planet uninhabitable with orbital bombardment.

This concept has a real-world equivalent in the from the Naval bombardment of an area to wipe out resistance, known as an [Alpha Strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_strike_(United_States_Navy)).

I am aware that list questions are not allowed, so I am not asking for a full list of all works that contain this type of life-wiping orbital bombardment strategy.   And I am aware that the idea probably originally came from the above-mentioned Alpha Strike.

What I am asking is, **when did the concept of an orbital bombardment of a planet, resulting in the death of *most* life** (Let's say, at least 70% of the dominant species being wiped out, assuming the dominant species is the intelligent, technology-using one), **all life, or rendering the planet uninhabitable, first make an appearance in Sci-Fi?**

Note that 'orbital bombardment' is a tricky thing to define.  [This Wiki definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_weapon#Orbital_bombardment) is pretty good, but I will also accept any attack if it originates in space, even if it is from a sattelite that originally came from the planet in question, comes from another planet and enters the atmosphere to deliver a deadly payload (so long as it is not a ground or sea invasion force, or a persistent atmospheric attack), or any other space-originating attack from outside or within a planet's orbit, so long as the attack is sufficiently devestating and leaves little to no room for retaliation from the surface.

Comment: Please define "orbital bombardment."

Comment: @KyleJones I"m not picky. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_weapon#Orbital_bombardment This will do.  And it doesn't matter what payload is delivered either.

Comment: The film "Starship Troopers" mentions "glassing the planet" from orbit

Comment: @Richard Not a bad place to start, but don't forget that Starship Troopers was a novel before it was a movie.

Comment: @Zibbobz - I don't consider the books to be canon in the Starship Troopers universe.

Comment: I suspect that the "death of all life or rendering the planet uninhabitable" part is going to be a sticking point for many possible answers.  You have to be pretty paranoid or pretty desperate to countenance that much indiscriminate killing.  Good sf has more nuanced aliens than that usually, Pellegrino notwithstanding.

Comment: I'd swear I first saw the actual term "glassing" (or some version of it) used in one of the first three Dune books, but I can't find the quote. If I can find it, I'll add that as part of an answer. I know for a fact that it was used in Heretics of Dune (1984), but that may not have been its first use. In that case it may have been literal - the Honored Matres' weapon burned so hot that it turned the sands of 'Rakis into actual glass.

Comment: @Richard - The movies aren't canon at all. They are their own separate universe that just stole the title.

Comment: @KyleJones, the Imperium of Man has little problem tossing a few Cyclonic Torpedoes at a planet even _suspected_ of being sufficient threat to the Imperium. (Or Two-Stage Cyclonic Torpedoes. Or Imperial Virus Bombs. Or extended orbital bombardment from the standard weapons of the Imperial Navy. Or, in one case, setting a Generatorium on the planet to overload.)

Comment: Two clarifications. (1) The Wikipedia definition of "orbital bombardment" is pretty strict. A bomb thrown by a spaceship doing a flyby does not count, right? (2) "death of all life" does not mean just **multicellular" life, does it? It includes bacteria residing deep underground? It's not clear to me that melting the surface necessarily going to sterilize the planet all the way down.

Comment: @Richard I seriously hope you are joking with regard to not considering the books canon - why ever not?!

Comment: I have edited the question to address certain issues with the term "orbital bombardment" and loosened the required amount of death (particularly since one of my references definitely has at least 6 humans survive such an attack, which is definitely more than 'all life'.)

Comment: @Moo - When compared with the elegant story-telling of the films the books pale into insignificance.

Comment: In Stanislaw Lems "Astronauts" (1951) the Venusians wanted to bombard Earth to wipe out life (but end up killing themselves and glassing their own planet).  However that's not from (Earth's) orbit but via a canon based on Venus, so this might not qualify as an answer.

Comment: @EikePierstorff See my last paragraph, where I try to broaden the scope of 'orbital bombardment' -  planet-to-planet would be fine, even if they're not really 'orbiting' Earth.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on what you consider an 'alpha-strike', you need to go back as far as "[A True Story](http://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/luc/true/tru01.htm)" by Lucian of Samosata in the 2nd Century.

The King of the Moon and the King of the Sun are fighting over the right to colonise Jupiter. The King of the Moon builds a giant web in space which blocks the Sun's rays, thus rendering the planet uninhabitable.

> As for us, we were taken off to the sun that day, our hands tied
>   behind our backs with a section of spider-web. The enemy decided not
>   to lay siege to the city, but on their way back they built a wall
>   through the air, so that the rays of the sun should no longer reach
>   the moon. The wall was double, made of cloud, so that a genuine
>   eclipse of the moon took place, and she was completely enshrouded in
>   unbroken night.

---

Failing that, the concept of planetary destruction (from space/with nukes) goes back at least as far as 1951:

> "This discussion is interesting, but futile," put in Eichlan,
>   forestalling a scornful reply. "It is more to the point, I think, to
>   discuss that which must be done; or, rather, who is to do it, since
>   the thing itself admits of only one solution—an atomic bomb of
>   sufficient power to destroy every trace of life upon that accursed
>   planet.

E. E. "Doc" Smith (1951), [Gray Lensman](http://freeread.com.au/@RGLibrary/EEDocSmith/Lensmen/GrayLensman.html)

Comment: I assume this quote is in reference to an atomic bomb delivered from a spaceship, and not from said planet itself, or from one planet to another?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Yes. The plan is to fly it to the planet and drop it on it.

Comment: "They fly it to the planet and drop it" is not **orbital** bombardment, **unless** they go into **orbit** about the planet before delivering the payload. Is it clear that that happens? As for Lucian's story, that doesn't remotely qualify: no orbit, no bombardment.

Comment: @user14111 - It's an attempt to render the planet uninhabitable from space. That sounds pretty close to me.

Comment: Close enough for me, too; but is it close enough for the OP? Asked to define "orbital bombardment" the OP referred to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_weapon#Orbital_bombardment) which defines the term strictly: "Orbital bombardment is the act of attacking targets on a planet, moon or other such object from *orbit* around the object, rather than from an aircraft, or a platform beyond orbit." A spaceship on a flyby is not in orbit around the planet, and is more like "a platform beyond orbit" which Wikipedia (the OP's authority for "orbital bombardment" specifically rules out.

Comment: Clearly an over-reliance on technological methods when a simpler solution is readily available. A 30-km diameter rock nudged out of it's stable orbit and steered into the path of the planet should take care of the problem nicely... :-)

Comment: I'll accept it on the grounds that you can definitely be in orbit and still drop something on a planet.  Just because *you* are going at a fast enough speed to counteract a planet's gravity doesn't mean your payload has to do it too (in fact, that would be a disasterous way to deliver a bomb).

Comment: I wonder if a single nuke or asteroid is actually a bombardment, at least under military terms it isn't.  Probably way too pedantic to matter in such a fun question =)

Comment: Instead of Lensmen, I would use Skylark 3 -- earlier and they destroy multiple planets with energy weapons.

Comment: Gray Lensman  was first published in Astounding Science Fiction starting in the October 1939 issue.  It also featured a planet sized mass of antimatter being smashed into a planet and to planets traveling in opposite directions being smashed to another planet.

Answer (score 3):

[This Island Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Island_Earth) circa 1955 has a planet being bombarded from space by programmed meteors.  Probably not the earliest, but pretty early.

Comment: Certainly one of the earliest in film fiction. You have my +1

Answer (score 2):

[The Moon is a Harsh Mistress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Is_a_Harsh_Mistress), published by Heinlein in 1966, is probably the most widely recognized introduction to orbital bombardment (which I'll define as kinetic bombardment using inert munitions against a target at the bottom of the gravity well).

I'm sure there's been earlier descriptions, but that one's pretty seminal.

Comment: Not bad thinking.  I admit I didn't think of lunar bombardment, but it's definitely a good answer.

Comment: Heinleins earlier Starship Troopers has reference to bombarding bug planets from orbit with nukes, turning the surface into radioactive glass, and that was in 1959.

Comment: @Moo, good catch, for some reason I thought Starship Troopers postdated TMIAHM.

Answer (score 2):

[Space Battleship Yamato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato)

The first season began airing in Japan on October 6, 1974. Set in the year 2199, an alien race known as the "Gamilas" ("Gamilons" in the English Star Blazers dub) unleash radioactive meteorite bombs on Earth, rendering the planet's surface uninhabitable.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty solid example.  Maybe not the earliest, but fairly early.

Comment: Perhaps one of the earliest examples on film?

Answer (score 2):

Not the first use of the concept but possibly the first use of the term "Glassing" is, as far as I can find it, in *[Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers)* in 1959 where they use it to describe what they do to the rest of Planet P during 'Operation Royalty'.

Comment: Not quite what the question is asking - but as far as interpreting it, this is a valid answer for when the *term* first came into circulation - so this is still a very good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Though this answer does not answer the question of the OP as well as previous answers I believe it does add some value.

Following are two much more recent examples of the use of the tactic of orbital bombardment to wipe out life on a planet, which are much more likely candidates as influences on the designers of Halo:

**[Babylon 5](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105946/)**
In the Babylon 5 series one of the major powers, the Shadows utilize a form of orbital bombardment to wipe out life on various offending planets.
(Their archenemies the Vorlon's also rendered numerous planets uninhabitable but, as I remember it, with a single enormously powerful shot from a non-kinetic energy weapon... which I would not call bombardment).

**[Robotech](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088595/?ref_=nv_sr_1)** (The Macros Saga)
Another reference from approximately 10yrs prior to Babylon 5 is Robotech. Toward the end of the first Robotech series the alien race the Zentradei begin the orbital bombardment of earth with the intent to destroy all life on it. The Zentradei efforts are interrupted and effectively stopped, however, it was most certainly their intent. 
Additional note: they did utilize non-kinetic energy weapons but the method was most certainly a bombardment of the planet.

Again I only mention these because they are more likely influences for the Halo designers than the early science fiction books previously mentioned, (and granted those answers are definitely better answers to the OP).

Answer (score 0):

If attacking a planet with death rays counts, the Prologue to *The triumph of Time* James Blish (1959) says that at The Battle of the Forts in 2413 the Third Colonial Navy under Admiral Alois Hrunta scorched the Vega system.

https://books.google.com/books?id=poAjCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT136&lpg=PT136&dq=cities+in+Space+planet+Vega+II&source=bl&ots=LNsSYmt4Cz&sig=qcrF6aqPlumPvZsiR2-OkUNu_eo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ5cyGnejRAhVBbiYKHfjDCGoQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=Alois%20Hrunta&f=false[1]

In the *Star Trek* episode "A Taste of Armageddon" 23 Feb, 1967:

> KIRK: All that it means is that I won't be around for the destruction. You heard me give General Order Twenty Four. That means in two hours the Enterprise will destroy Eminiar Seven.
>
> KIRK: Kirk to Enterprise. Scotty? 
>   SCOTT [OC]: Scott here, Captain. 
>   KIRK: Cancel implementation of General Order Twenty Four. Alert transporter room. We're ready to beam up.

http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/23.htm[2]

And in "Where No Man Has Gone before" 22 Sep, 1966:

> KIRK: If you have not received a signal from me within twelve hours, you'll proceed at maximum warp to the nearest Earth base with my recommendation that this entire planet be subjected to a lethal concentration of neutron radiation. No protest on this, Mark. That's an order.

http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/2.htm[3]

So apparently the *Enterprise* had a significant weapons upgrade between the two episodes or didn't have enough power left to devastate a planet in "Where No Man Has Gone before" after being damaged by the galactic barrier.

Answer (score -3):

Nevil Shute's "On The Beach" (1957) talks about the end of human life on earth after a Nuclear War.

H. Beam Piper's (1957) "The Keeper" takes place on an Earth that was bombarded into an ice age by warfare in the future.

I'd think that 1945 would be a good place to start looking back, as from then Nuking out life on Earth was a common trope.

Comment: I don't see how either of these stories meet the criteria; planetary bombardment

Comment: neither do any of the other answers

Comment: @Oldcat This doesn't make your answer any better.